# java.lang.AssertionError: expected <0> but was <48>

Tags: java, junit

So, i am supposed to correct the bug in a java function, which i mostly did (it was an "index out of range" error), but now i get this error message and i'd like to understand where the 48 is coming from.

The function in itself:

```
 public char firstRepeatedCharacter() {
    for (int i = 0; i < (word.length()-1); i++) {
      char ch = word.charAt(i);
      if (ch == word.charAt(i + 1))
        return ch;
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

(i added the "-1" to correct the "index out of range" error.)

and my test functions made with JUnit:

```
public class WordAnalyzerTest {
  @Test
  public void shouldTestaardvark() {
      WordAnalyzer wa = new WordAnalyzer("aardvark");
      char result = wa.firstRepeatedCharacter();
      assertEquals(result,'a');
  }
  @Test
  public void shouldTestroommate() {
      WordAnalyzer wa = new WordAnalyzer("roommate");
      char result = wa.firstRepeatedCharacter();
      assertEquals(result,'o');
  }
  @Test
  public void shouldTestmate() {
      WordAnalyzer wa = new WordAnalyzer("mate");
      char result = wa.firstRepeatedCharacter();
      assertEquals(result,'0');
  }
  @Test
  public void shouldTesttest() {
      WordAnalyzer wa = new WordAnalyzer("test");
      char result = wa.firstRepeatedCharacter();
      assertEquals(result,'0');
  }
}
```

The error message happens when Eclipse gets to the last two tests, the first two run correctly.

Where does the "48" come from?

Edit: Thanks guys, it worked!

Comment: `48` is ascii char code value of `'0'`: https://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: 48 is the Unicode codepoint representing the character `0`. In other words: `'0' != 0`.

Comment: @luk2302: I think we should all work towards eliminating the false believe that "ASCII" is still somehow relevant in todays world and the page you linked to even provides an "extended ASCII table" which is highly misleading at least (and I'd argue outright wrong in many cases).